# Performance comparison between Pivot vs Filters+Joins

Tags: python, database, pyspark, bigdata

I would like to ask you opinion about the following question:

From a **computational effort point of view**, in a pyspark environment, would you advise to use a pivot function or a series of filtered tables and joins to carry out the same result? And why?

From my point of view, despite coding a pivot should be faster, I would prefer a series of joins on filtered results because it wouldn’t require any transposition on the dataframe, but I am here to ask you opinion in order to learn more about it!

Thanks

Comment: I am also interested in this, if I have a large dataset (~1 million rows) does it make more sense to pivot rows to 1 row or filter/join?